# How to prove that $r(s,t)=exp{(\lambda\ (exp{(i(s-t))}-1))}$ ($\lambda$ is positive) is covariance function of some stochastic process?

Tags: stochastic-processes, covariance, poisson-process

One guy told me that showing Hermite symmetry and positive semidefinite would be enough here. 
But I still don't know how to explain it if it's right. 
Hermit symmetry is obvious. 
And I do not know how to prove that this function is positive semidefinite (I know the definition of positive semidefinite function!)

Comment: You might recognize $t\mapsto \exp(\lambda(e^{it}-1))$ as the characteristic function of some real random variable, and appeal to Bochner's theorem.

Comment: Good idea, thank you!